# How to prevent Angular from continuing to render a directive (with wrong results) after error thrown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have some directives with a template and a `compile` function that alters the template. Sometimes Angular will fail to detect jQuery (and use jqLite), which causes my `compile` to throw. However, Angular would continue to render the template in the directive and then the rest of the page.

This is awful as the unaltered template often contains misleading or wrong information. Does anyone know why it is like this and how to prevent it?

Comment: Could whomever downvoted care to explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented an `$exceptionHandler` which will replace the whole page with some debugging info. Angular would continue to render as described above but just to elements no longer in the DOM.